# What is the semistable reduction for sheaves?

Tags: moduli-spaces, coherent-sheaves

Let $\Bbbk$ be an algebraically closed field with characteristic zero. Let $X$ be a projective scheme over $\Bbbk$ and let $L$ be an ample invertible $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. Fix a Hilbert polynomial $P(t)$. Let $M^{ss}$ denote the moduli space of semistable sheaves with Hilbert polynomial $P(t)$ and let $M^s\subseteq M^{ss}$ denote the moduli space of stable sheaves.

It is well known that $M^{ss}$ is projective, and then the valuative criterion holds. Also $M^{s}$ is the étale sheafification of moduli functor $\mathbf{M}^{\prime,s}:(\mathit{Sch}/\Bbbk)^{opp}\to \mathit{Sets}$
$$\mathbf{M}^{\prime,s}(T):=\{\textrm{flat }T\textrm{-families of geometrically stable sheaves of }P(t)\}/\textrm{isomorphism}.$$

We unfold the valuative criterion. Let $A$ be a discrete valuation ring over $\Bbbk$. Let $\mathbb{K}$ be its field of fractions and let $\kappa$ be its residue field. Assume we have a stable sheaf over $X_{\mathbb{K}}$, inducing a morphism $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{K})\to M^s$.

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{K})@>>>M^s@>>>M^{ss}\\
@VVV@VVV@VVV\\
\mathrm{Spec}(A)@>>>\mathrm{Spec}(\Bbbk)@=\mathrm{Spec}(\Bbbk)
\end{CD}
$$
The valuative criterion implies the existence of $\mathrm{Spec}(A)\to M^{ss}$ in the diagram.

My question is the following.

> Given $A\subseteq\mathbb{K}$ and a stable sheaf over $X_{\mathbb{K}}$ as above, in what sense can we say there is a flat family of semistable sheaves over $A$, representing the unique morhpism $\mathrm{Spec}(A)\to M^{ss}$?